# Mouse button and keypress counter for Windows

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard, mouse-buttons, counter

I am trying to kick the habit of using a mouse where I could use keyboard shortcuts, for ergonomic reasons. I believe that if I see some statistics of my use of both input devices, I could reduce my use of mouse clicks.
Do you know of any free software I can install on my Windows XP machine that counts keypresses and mouse button presses and displays an hourly/daily report?
No fancy GUI is needed - just two summary lines.

Comment: You could always electrify your mouse button... :)

Comment: Or just unplug your mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

[Gabe's TypOmeter](https://web.archive.org/web/20171025042213/http://www.informatics.no:80/progvareTMLoc.htm)

From the site:

> "Display system information!"

> EditByBSEditor: 1.Mouse Click counter
> The Mouse Click counter shows the
> number of mouse clicks you have
> performed since you started the
> TypOmeter.

> 2.Speedometer The Speedometer shows the speed you are typing with. The
> speed is measured in keystrokes pr
> minute. The range of the speedometer
> is from zero to 900 keystrokes pr
> minute. The speedometer scale has
> indicators for every 150 keystrokes pr
> minute.

> 3.Max Speed indicator The Max Speed indicator shows the the maximum speed
> you have typed with the last ten
> seconds. It uses the same scale as the
> Speedometer. If you concentrate on the
> typing a while, you can watch this
> indicator afterwards to check how fast
> you typed the last couple of
> sentences.

> 4.Over All Total counter (x1000) The Over All Total counter shows number of
> thousands keypress and MouseClicks you
> have performed ever. (At least as long
> as you have used the TypOmeter...)

> 5.Key Press counter The Key Press counter shows the number of keypresses
> you have performed since you started
> the TypOmeter.

> 6.Word Counter The Word Counter shows you how many words you have typed.
> This feature works best while writing
> prosa, i.e. like writing a
> Word-document. Please also see the the
> Word pr minute indicator.

> 7.Max Speed Reached indicator This inidcator will get red if your typing
> speed exeeds 900 keystrokes pr minute,
> which is the limit of the TypOmeter.

> 8. Bad Key indicator The red area shows the amount of Backspace and
>    Delete Key-hits you have performed
>    today, in percent of total keypresses.
>    The red area should of course be as
>    small as possible.

And the best part :

License: Freeware Free

Comment: Hi!
I've been trying to install Gabe's TypOmeter, but it doesn't work on windows 7 so can you tell me if there's another programme which can do the same. It doesn't need to be free.

Comment: This product was last developed in 2002 and it is a 16-bit application that doesn't work in modern versions of Windows. If you have a 64-bit operating system, it refuses to install itself.

Answer (score 1):

This application is so old that it doesn't work in modern versions of Windows. While asking the same question on a different thread, I have found a very useful app that works on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux. It's named [WhatPulse](https://whatpulse.org/) and you can learn more about how it works, here: 
[How many key presses and mouse clicks do you perform in a day?](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-many-key-presses-and-mouse-clicks-you-perform-day)

Answer (score 0):

This is a keypress counter only but I found it useful enough to share:

**[KeyCounter](https://www.dcmembers.com/skwire/download/keycounter/)**

[image: KeyCounter interface]

KeyCounter is a keystrokes counting software here. It tracks every single key separately and shows how many times you pressed a particular key. Apart from this, total keystrokes are also provided by this software. You can also export the data as CSV file. Whenever you want, you can also reset the counts to start with a fresh count.

Another interesting feature of this software is that you can select which keystroke groups you want to track. For example, you can select only ‘a-z’, or function keys (F1-F12) to track.

It is portable and very lightweight.