# Program that can count the most frequently used keys pressed on keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mouse button and keypress counter for Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/117801/mouse-button-and-keypress-counter-for-windows-xp)

Any recommendations on a program that I can manually start/stop to run in the background that will measure (count) how many times a key is pressed on the keyboard?  As a software developer, I'd like to know which keys are used the most when I develop from project to project and/or from language to language.

- I'd like to be able to manually start and stop the program.
- This is for a Windows PC (xp, vista, 7)

Comment: The answer in the other question is what you want: http://informatics.no/progvareTMLoc.htm

Comment: @Ivo - you might want to check that link (and delete my comment just after)

Comment: @Gnoupi they try to stop deeplinking apparently, but this one directs to the right page

Comment: @Ivo - it was only surprising to see this link when I was rather expecting a link to the other question, according to the earlier text, that's why I wrote that, simply.

Comment: @Gnoupi the link is already at the top of the screen :-P But I could have phrased it differently. I just need a secretary to type out what I want to say in a concise way