# Mouse button and keypress counter for Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, mouse, monitoring, x-windows

I would like to have some kind of statistic of my daily mouse/keyboard usage to help me make my keyboard layout a little bit more efficient.

There is already a question about [how to do this on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/117801/mouse-button-and-keypress-counter-for-windows-xp), but I would like to know I anyone is aware if this is possible under linux. Another thing I already found is [key-mon](http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/), a little program for screencasts that displays your mouse and keyboard presses on the screen, which would help me achieve what I want with a little bit of python coding by myself. But still, if there was an solution already, that would be easier of course.

Comment: i've tweaked the position of your first link, and incorporated your second link.  until you gain some more rep you'll have to rely on other users to add multiple links for you (sorry), but you can always stick additional links in comments if you need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just wrote a program that does this myself, so here's a shameless plug:

https://github.com/forsberg/kbdcounter

Comment: It's been 11 years so [I forked this project](https://github.com/esauvisky/kbdcounter), updated to python3 and am adding some features like a heatmap display and better statistics reporting. Thanks for your work.