# Click counter for windows + online stats?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse, mouse-click

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mouse button and keypress counter for Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/117801/mouse-button-and-keypress-counter-for-windows-xp)

So I would like to be able to see how many times a day I click my mouse and then be able to view these stats online. Much like scrobbling, only with how many times I click my mouse.

Does such a thing exist for windows?

I know of the mac version: http://www.murgaa.com/mac-mouse-click-counter/

Comment: that is pretty good thanks, only thing its lacking is the online part... :/

Comment: plus, unfortunatly it doesn't work with windows 7 :(

Comment: Have you tried a search for "[Windows Mouse Click Counter](https://www.google.com/search?q=Windows+Mouse+Click+Counter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)"? Lots of information there. The only thing is to be careful as this is a great way for key-loggers to get your passwords and such.

Comment: Still don't think this should have been close as mentioned it doesn't have the online part, but i'll assume it doesn't exist then.